# How to save data with selected variables in R?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

Let's say I have data with 1000 variables. The dataset is a `.csv` and I read it using: `mydata<- read.csv2("dataset.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")`.

How do I save `mydata` with selected variables? I usually use `write.csv2(mydata, "~/Desktop/newdata.csv")` -- is it possible to select certain variable within `write.csv2`? If not, what are the other options?

Comment: Without trying, I would be astounded if `write.csv2(mydata[, c(<selected variables>)], "~/Desktop/newdata.csv")` doesn't work. Note `<selected variables>`  is either numeric indices or variable names.

Comment: Or `mydata[[c(...)]]` or `subset(mydata, select=c(...))` or `dplyr::select(mydata, c(...))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
write.csv(dataframename[,c("a","b")], file="~/Desktop/newdata.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

`dataframename[rows,cols]` select rows and columns of a data frame.